# Mongo and handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi guys so recently l've been learning handlebars and creating an app with express and mongodb and using handlebars as the templating engine but l'm having a small problem with making my update and delete button work. This is my code and what l  tried doing :

//these are my methods that l am using to do update and delete. the requests are working properly in postman but cant seem to figure out how to connect them to my handlebars

```
app.put('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id + " was hit")
  const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
  const user = { name: req.body.name, surname: req.body.surname, cellphone: req.body.cellphone};
  db.collection('users').update(details, user, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
    } else {
      res.send(user);
    } 
  });
});



app.delete('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
  db.collection('users').remove(details, (err, item) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
    } else {
      res.send('User ' + id + ' deleted!');
    } 
  });
});
```

And in my template l have this:

```
<div class="col-8">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cellphone</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {{#each users}}
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{surname}}</td>
                    <td>{{cellphone}}</td>
                     <span>
                        <a href="/users/{{_id}}" title="Delete this todo item">Delete</a>
                     </span>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </div>
```

but when l press the delete button this l am getting the ReferenceError: id is not defined error and also tried to change _id to id in my handlebars but l'm not going anywhere with my delete function.

Comment: An `a` tag makes a GET request, not a DELETE request. So when you click on that button, it's not going to be handled by the `app.delete` handler. You'll need to use javascript to send a DELETE request to that endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, what l finally did to tackle the challenge after the helpful comment that you posted to l actually change the call to make it a Post instead of delete and also in the html l change it from delete to post plus l stoped using the href and instead used this in my handlebars

<td><form action="/users/{{_id}}" method="POST">
                            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="Delete" value="POST"></input>
                        </form></td>


its was the temporary fix until l come up with a better solution. Thanks a lot for the help, truly appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a `DELETE` http request with a link using an `<a>` tag.
You should note that html links created by `<a>` tags, make the browser to make a `GET` http request.

---

#### Solution #1 (Recommended):

The best way to come around this issue is to use a http client library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Here is an example using axios:

Markup:

```
<button onclick="deleteToDoItem( {{_id}} )"> Delete </button>
```

Javascript:

```
function deleteToDoItem(id) {
    axios.delete("/users/"+id).then(function(response) {
        console.log("Item Deleted");
    })
}
```

---

#### Solution #2:

As an alternative solution, you can come around this issue by somehow  overriding the original http request method in your backend code.

Check this project out for inspiration: https://github.com/expressjs/method-override.

This lets you achieve the desired results by changing your markup to something like this:

```
<a href="/users/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE" title="Delete this todo item">Delete</a>
```